# How to refresh OpenCV window while holding down keys

Tags: python, opencv

While I keep key pressed the window is frozen and refreshes only after a key is released (skipping frames while key is pressed). How do I refresh window without repeatedly clicking keys?

```py
while True:
   cv2.imshow('image', next_frame())
   key = cv2.waitKeyEx()
```

Comment: `cv2.waitKeyEx()` this is the same as `cv2.waitKeyEx(0)` which as it is explained in the documentation it will wait for a key to be pressed to continue. If you put any number instead like `cv2.waitKeyEx(10)` it will wait 10 ms before continuing the loop without the need to press any key.

Comment: this is **probably** an issue of how OpenCV uses various GUI toolkits to process GUI events. I've noticed this too, with keyboard input and with mouse events. if you're lucky, someone will notice and work on patches...

Answer (score 1):

Following trick works for me but I fear that it is just a random coincidence.

```py
while True:
   cv2.imshow('image', next_frame())
   key = cv2.waitKeyEx()
   cv2.waitKeyEx(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, the window wouldn't update when the key was pressed for sequentially showing the next picture. Adding an 1ms `waitKey` solves this problem:

```
icur = 0
while True:
    img = cv2.imread(images[icur])
    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1) # force refreshing the window
    key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    if key == 27:
        break
    elif key == 81:
        icur = max(icur - 1, 0)
    elif key == 83:
        icur = min(icur + 1, len(images) - 1)
```

Comment: You lose info about any key pressed during processing of imread and imshow because you are using result of the second waitkey. Also it is duplicate of my answer (except the described issue) .